# upload multiple in ionic framework

Tags: ionic-framework

I want to upload multiple images to a remote server,
I try cordovaFileTransfer but i get error

> ReferenceError: fileURL is not defined

Controller js

```
.controller("UploadController", function($scope, $cordovaFileTransfer) {

$scope.upload = function() {
    var options = {
        fileKey: "avatar",
        fileName: "image.png",
        chunkedMode: false,
        mimeType: "image/png"
    };
    $cordovaFileTransfer.upload("api/upload_image", fileURL.substr(fileURL.lastIndexOf('/') + 1) , options).then(function(result) {
        console.log("SUCCESS: " + JSON.stringify(result.response));
    }, function(err) {
        console.log("ERROR: " + JSON.stringify(err));
    }, function (progress) {
        // constant progress updates
    });
}
```

})

View

```
<div ng-controller="UploadController">
    <a class="button button-stable button-block select_cats" ng-click="upload()">Upload Images</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Where you define your fileURL ??

Comment: please refer this link https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2015/01/upload-files-remote-server-using-ionic-framework/

Comment: how i can change "/android_asset/www/img/ionic.png" to selected images Or How i can define fileURL